# RedirectToAction after successful post to show a message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When people register on my ASP.NET MVC website I send an activation link via email so they can activate their account and login. I want to show a message when the registration is successful and the email is sent. To do that I redirect to another page.

I do not want to show this page when people go directly to this URL because it is not a normal page. I use TempData to check if they are coming from the registration page.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    AccountRegisterView accountView = InitializeAccountRegisterViewWithIssue(false, "");

    return View(accountView);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(AccountRegisterView accountView)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(accountView);
    }

    // Register user and send activation link via email...

    TempData["success"] = true;

    return RedirectToAction("RegisterEmail");
}

public ActionResult RegisterEmail()
{
    if (TempData["success"] != null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

I would like to know if this is considered best practice. Or should I do this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly good use of `TempData[]`.  You need a variable for a one time request to decide if you should show the page or not.

I suppose you could use a session variable, but you would need to remember to clear the session.  You could use some type of registration key, but then you would need to track those as well.  Long story short, nope, you are good.