# Show a message after redirecting after a successful POST request without using TempData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am using the [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.
In my asp.net core MVC web app, this is what happens:

1. User submits a form via POST which adds an item to db.
2. Controller adds the new item and redirects with 302/303 to "/Home/Index/xxxx", where xxxx is the id of the item.
3. The new request (/Home/Index/xxxx) is served by the controller, and it displays the item. And the item url in the address bar is something the user can copy and share.

At step 3 above, I would like to show the user a message saying "Item was successfully added".

This is my code (without the success message):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    ItemView itemView = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        itemView = new ItemView();  // Create an empty item.
    else
        itemView = await itemService.GetItemAsync(id);
    return View(itemView);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ItemView itemView)
{
    string id = await itemService.AddItemAsync(itemView);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = id });
}
```

There are few ways to do this that I found in other answers on stackoverflow.

1. Redirect to "/Home/Index/xxxx?success=true". When action sees a success=true param, it can display the success message. But I don't want to use an extra param because I would like users to be able to just copy the url from the address bar and share it. And I don't want them sharing the url that has success param, because then everyone who clicks on the shared link will see the message "Item was successfully added".
2. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954397/redirecttoaction-after-successful-post-to-show-a-message) suggests using TempData, which is a good solution. I think that would need me to enable sticky behavior on the server, which I would like to avoid if possible.
3. I can probably use referrer url to determine if the request came after a form submission, and in that case I can show the message.

Comment: According to your scenario,I would recommend to use TempData.

Comment: Those down voting this, would you mind leaving a comment explaining why? Did I use too many tags? Or does the question look like a duplicate? I did do thorough research, and listed some of the commonly suggested solutions (and linked one) and explained why I was still looking for answers. And snoopy's answer below helped me find the right solution.

Comment: I had a similar response to a question where I was in a similar dilemma. I knew how to do it one way, but I wasn't a fan of that method due to our network infrastructure, and threw a couple ideas out of possible alternatives that I didn't know how to properly implement. I guess people see "This person is asking which way is better, therefore it's opinion-based and not a real question." Instead of "Hey, this guy's at least thinking of possible solutions instead of just posting a question and asking everyone to figure it out for him."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The original answer by "snoopy" did point me in the right direction. But for some unknown reason, that answer no longer exists, so I am posting the answer myself in the hope it would benefit someone in future.*

ASP .NET Core 1.1 and higher supports Cookie based Tempdata provider called CookieTempDataProvider. Link to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state).

This is similar to Session based Tempdata, but no data is stored on the server side. The response from the server set's a cookie in the browser with the data you want to store. The next request from the browser will include this cookie. The framework automatically parses this and populates this in TempData, which the controller can use. Once the controller reads this data, then the CookieTempDataProvider automatically adds the appropriate headers in the response to clear this cookie.

In your Startup class's ConfigureServices method, you need to register CookieTempDataProvider:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
```

To store some data in cookie based temp data, you simple set the value like this in your controller:

```
TempData["key"] = "value";
```

To read the data in your controller, you read it like this:

```
string value = TempData["key"];
if (value != null)
{
  // Do something with the the value.
}
```

The check for non-null tells you if that key exists in TempData or not. Note that you can also check using .ContainsKey() method, but that is not counted as a read. The data (& the cookie) will not be cleared unless you read it. For example this will not clear the data:

```
if (TempData.ContainsKey("key"))
{
// Do something without actually reading the value of TempData["key"].
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: For .net core 2.0 and later, the cookie-based temp data provider is included in the middleware by default.